# How to read integers properly in fortran90 when the input file has both integer and text?

Tags: integer, fortran90

This is my data file `a.txt`

```
01 12  00 10  Nothing to do
```

To be clear let me mark the white spaces with * `01*12**00*10**Nothing*to*do`.

I am trying to read it with a fortran90 code

```
implicit none
integer           :: a,b,c,d
character(len=16) :: ch

print*,"Case1"
open(unit=10,file="a.txt", form="formatted")
read(10,*)a,b,c,d,ch
write(*,"(4(i2.2,1x),a16)")a,b,c,d,ch
close(10)

print*,"Case2"
open(unit=10,file="a.txt", form="formatted")
read(10,"(4i2,a16)")a,b,c,d,ch
write(*,"(4(i2.2,1x),a16)")a,b,c,d,ch
close(10)

print*,"Case3"
open(unit=10,file="a.txt", form="formatted")
read(10,"(4(i2,1x),a16)")a,b,c,d,ch
write(*,"(4(i2.2,1x),a16)")a,b,c,d,ch
close(10)

end
```

And this is the output

```
 Case1
01 12 00 10 Nothing         
 Case2
01 01 02 00 0 10  Nothing to
 Case3
01 12 00 01   Nothing to do
```

As you can see, the integers are read correctly when I don't specify the data type (Case1), but the character is not read properly.
When I specify them as integer (Case2), the leading `0` is neglected and each digit is considered giving a wrong string.
When I also specify the white space to be `1x` (Case3) first two integers are read properly but it can not pick up the third one as there is two spaces. Since it is not always possible to know all the spaces in a given file, this method would not be very practical either.

How to read this data properly?

I got same result with `gcc version 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-39) (GCC)`, `gcc version 8.2.0 (GCC)` and `ifort version 19.0.3.199`.

### Edit

If the input contains only integers, one can use the methods described in [Reading a sequence of integer in a line with unknown bound in fortran](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32022062/reading-a-sequence-of-integer-in-a-line-with-unknown-bound-in-fortran)

```
implicit none
integer           :: nums(4)
character(len=30) :: ch, ch1

open(unit=10,file="a.txt", form="formatted")
read(10,"(a)")ch
read(ch,*) nums,ch1

write(*,"(a)")ch
write(*,"(4(i2.2,1x),a16)")nums,ch1

close(10)
end
```

And we are back to Case1.

```
01 12  00 10  Nothing to do   
01 12 00 10 Nothing
```

Comment: Case 3 you say is read correctly, but the output appears to have a `01` rather than `10`: which is correct?  Note also that you appear to be testing whether the string is _read_ correctly by looking at the _processed output_: are you sure it hasn't been read correctly?

Comment: @francescalus, you are correct. The reading is wrong. The output is copy-paste of code output from terminal. I'll edit/correct it.

Comment: Do you have the possibility of pre-processing `a.txt` before reading it with fortran? take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38133083/fortran-read-mixed-text-and-numbers). It provides a suggestion with pre-processing and also a suggestion without pre-processing. Personally, I always pre-process  text files using `sed`, `awk`, `tr`, etc. *"the right tool for the right job"*